# JWT token is not passing in header in angular6

Tags: angular

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let request = req.clone({
      setHeaders: this.getRequestHeaders()
    });
    return next.handle(request).map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse && event.status==200) {
      } else 
      console.log('event =', event, ';');
      return event;
    })
    .catch((err: any, caught) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        let error=err['error']
        // if (err['error'] && (err['error']['status'] == 401) && (err['error']['message']=="Session Expired,please login Again.") || err['error']['message']=="Full authentication is required to access this resource") {
        //   setTimeout(()=>{
        //     this.localStorageService.clearLocalStorage();
        //     return this.router.navigate(['/login']);              
        //   }, 1000);
        // }
        return Observable.throw(error);
      }
    });
  }

  public getRequestHeaders(){
    let token=this.localStorageService.getToken();
    let headers={'Accept':  'application/json'};
    if(token){
      headers['Authorisation']=token;
    }
    return headers;
  }
```

> I have implemented interceptor service but token is not passing in
>   passing in header and nothing is working because of that. I fetch the
>   token from local storage but is showing nothing

Comment: Try to log the token

Comment: token is showing null because local storage would be empty before login

Comment: First you need to set token in localstorage then only u can get

Comment: I have already done this

Comment: Have you stored as key value?

Comment: yes, But for example if I am hitting a API which does not need token then in that Token will not pass.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set header you must create header instance like this. Below is my example

```
  private initAuthHeaders(): Headers {
    const token = this.getLocalToken();
    const headers = new Headers();
    if (token !== null) {
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    }
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }
```